# VS2012 VB: integer becomes float in code-editor

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Well as the title says I have a very annoying issue. 
This only occurs when i code VBprojects in VS2012, I haven't seen the same thing when coding c#projects in same envorinment.

So when I've typed an integer, eg. 1, then when I press enter to go to a new line the 1 magically transforms into 0.99999999999. And also if I eg. type 1.25, after I press enter the number tranforms into 1.2444444444444

Is there some configsetting I can change?

Comment: Are you saying if you typed `Dim i As Integer = 1` then hit enter that _1_ would become _0.99999999999_?

Comment: Show code; switch on option strict.

Comment: @Jinx88909 precisely what I'm saying.

Comment: @user3532232 that is bizarre. You've no Third Party Addons installed have you that could maybe cause this? Turn **Option Strict On** as suggested by peterG and see what happens. It should cause a compile error.

Comment: Only thing  have is ankhSVN. @peterG where do I find option strict? Have serached in Tools->Options->Text Editor->VB but can't find it.

Comment: Project properties > Compile tab. (Really I should just say LMGTFY :) )

Comment: **Tools** -> **Options** -> **Projects and Solutions** -> **VB Defaults** will set it as the default for all future projects.  Project-> properties ...etc... for the current project